# Formula for $S_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I need help deriving a formula for the nth partial sum of the following infinite series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\left[\ln\left(\sqrt{n\,+\,1}\right)\ -\ \ln\left(\sqrt{n}\right)\right]$$

I thought that I would combine the terms into a single logarithm, but after that I hit a brick wall.

Comment: Perhaps a typo, we don't want to start at $n=0$.

Comment: You should take the minimum effort to expand a few terms by hand to see the telescoping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: It is a [telescoping sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

My suggestion is to write out the first few, and last few terms of the partial sum $s_k$. You should see that all of the terms in the middle cancel out.

Answer (score 1):

$$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^N (\ln \sqrt{n+1}-\ln \sqrt{n} )=\ln \sqrt{N+1}-\ln 1=\ln \sqrt{N+1}$$

Comment: The first term (for $n=0$) is undefined–zero does not belong to the logarithm's domain. Try summing from $n=1$.

Comment: Oops! Correct. I am editing it. Thanks for pointing out @CiaPan.